# AutoHotkey script stopped working after I downgraded to windows 7 from windows 10

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

An AutoHotkey script stopped working adter I downgraded to Windows 7 from Windows 10:

- Script is started via shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- Monitor wakes via <kbd>ESC</kbd> only, but doen't wake if I uncomment `DllCall("LockWorkStation")`:

  ```ini
  #NoEnv                        ; # Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
  ; #Warn                       ; # Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.

  SendMode Input                ; # Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
  SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%   ; # Ensures a consistent starting directory.

  ;^!l:: Run C:\Users\root\Desktop\Погасить_экран\TCIMG.exe monof=2||({SPACE}, {ESC}, {F9})

  Loop
  {
    Sleep, 200 ; pause
  ;  DllCall("LockWorkStation")
    Sleep, 200 ; pause
    SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, 2,, Program Manager ; # 0x112 is WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF170 is SC_MONITORPOWER.
  }

  ~ESC:: ; ESC - stop script
    SendMessage, 0x112, 0xF170, -1,, Program Manager ; # turn on monitor
    ExitApp ; exit
  Return ;
  ```

Comment: Is this a fairly new computer? It may not be Windows 7 compliant.  Was this computer originally running Windows 7? You may need to run a Windows 7 Repair with the Windows 7 DVD.

Comment: oh no. it's around 2010 year of birth. this script worked at win 10 on this PC, but not working at this PC at win 7. Monitor doens't wake up if i use DllCall("LockWorkStation") string

Comment: Try the Windows 7 Repair to fix the issue.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Try this tutorial to repair the Windows 7 installation. I am thinking something went wrong going backwards from Windows 10 to Windows 7 especially since Windows 7 is now long out of support.   http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: It was clean install. Two days ago. It wasn't a downgrade procedure. Script turns off monitor without locking PC. Win+l separately works. But toghether pc locks, monitor off, but i can wake it up. Only reset button is helping.